# Convert list of headers into rows. Pandas dataframe | csv

Tags: json, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a nested json, which i flattened to make a pandas Df which looks like..

```
data_0_id, data_0_rank, data_0symbol,data_1_id, data_1_rank,    data_1_symbol.. till data_10_id,    data_10_rank,   data_10_symbol.
```

I am struggling to convert this into dataset where these headers get appended to respective header group n not append sideways.
Example-

```
Id, Rank, Symbol
data of data_0_id , data of data_0_rank, data of data_0_symbol
data of data_1_id , data of data_1_rank, data of data_1_symbol
data of data_2_id , data of data_2_rank, data of data_2_symbol
data of data_3_id , data of data_3_rank, data of data_3_symbol
...
data of data_10_id , data of data_10_rank, data of data_10_symbol
```

I have used 'melt' function in pandas but not getting what I want.

Many thanks in advance if someone can help me here.

Attaching some screenshots as well for better understanding.

[image]

Edit-2 for "@mozway".

My initial csv after parsing looks like this
[image]

the code I have written with your help-

```
from module_flatten_json import flatten_json
import json
import pandas as pd

file =open('./response11.json')
json_file = json.load(file)

flatten_json_data = flatten_json(json_file)

dff = pd.DataFrame(flatten_json_data,['key'])
# dff.to_csv('./dff13feb2.csv')


out = (dff.set_axis(dff.columns.str.rsplit('_', n=0, expand=True), axis=1)
         .stack(1)
         .reset_index(drop=True) # optional
      )

print(out)

# out.to_csv('./out.csv')
```

The output looks like this -
[image]

The columns like 'skills.name', 'skills.level' , 'additional_info.thesis_topic' , 'additional_info.advisor'

are the one which are different from other header groups.

Is there any way to get a prettier dataframe as the final output ?

A transposed output of initial dataset (3 sets of values)
Yellow and Pink Marked are extra columns in these sets,
blues are the repeating ones, which I am trying to stack.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this kind of input:

```
   data_0_id  data_0_rank  data_0_symbol  data_1_id  data_1_rank  data_1_symbol  data_10_id  data_10_rank  data_10_symbol
0          0            1              2          3            4              5           6             7               8
```

You could use [`str.rsplit`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rsplit.html) to form a MultiIndex, then [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
out = (df.set_axis(df.columns.str.rsplit('_', n=1, expand=True), axis=1)
         .stack(0)
         .reset_index(drop=True) # optional
      )
```

Output:

```
   id  rank  symbol
0   0     1       2
1   3     4       5
2   6     7       8
```

Intermediate before `reset_index`:

```
           id  rank  symbol
0 data_0    0     1       2
  data_1    3     4       5
  data_10   6     7       8
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I have reached somewhere with your help. Although , I am getting errors - outof index.  so I changed n=0 and stack(1) . There is still some complexity remaining in my flattened data. There can be 1 -2 nested list in between, due to which there are many more columns added to the header. I will update the question and add screenshot. Thanks again for your help. Can you take a look if this can be improved ?

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a [mre] that triggers this error.